# Select Distinct Values, Pass Into Where Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to look at unique values in my table, and based on n number of values returned from the distinct query, pass those into a subsequent query in my **WHERE** clause.

Let me provide an example.

I have the a Table with the following columns:

```
ID | UserName | OtherCondition
```

I usually compute the total records, those which match a **WHERE** clause on **OtherCondition**, and their related percentages, as such:

```
SELECT 'Report' as ReportName,
COUNT(*) Match, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [MyTable) Total,
CAST(COUNT(*) AS FLOAT)/CAST((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [MyTable]) AS FLOAT)*100 Percentage
FROM [MyTable]   
WHERE OtherCondition = MyCondition
```

Now, I am trying to integrate the UserName column into this query. By this I mean, what would happen is I look through the above table, and get all the unique usernames for all records (this can potentially be empty/null as well). This username would be passed into **ReportName** (currently a string literal) in the above (in the format of something like 'Report - ' [username]), and this would also be passed into a second WHERE condition. In totality, the WHERE condition would then look like:

```
WHERE OtherCondition = MyCondition AND UserName = [The Passed in unique username, from the not yet defined query]
```

Essentially, this would allow me to find all the unique users, and provide user based reporting.

Some sample data:

```
ID | UserName | OtherCondition
1    Mary         X
2    John         X
3    Mary         X
```

Expected Results:

```
 SELECT 'Report - Mary' as ReportName,
    COUNT(*) Match, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [MyTable) Total,
    CAST(COUNT(*) AS FLOAT)/CAST((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [MyTable]) AS FLOAT)*100 Percentage
    FROM [MyTable]   
    WHERE OtherCondition = x AND UserName = 'Mary'


 SELECT 'Report - John' as ReportName,
    COUNT(*) Match, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [MyTable) Total,
    CAST(COUNT(*) AS FLOAT)/CAST((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [MyTable]) AS FLOAT)*100 Percentage
    FROM [MyTable]   
    WHERE OtherCondition = x AND UserName = 'John'
```

Comment: Your question is very confusing. Perhaps putting together a sqlfiddle along with the desired output would help. I just don't get at all what you are trying to do.

Comment: I will try. As a clarification, I am trying to make a report by username, that matches a constant where condition. Meaning, in this case, OtherCondition = MyCondition (this will always be the case) however I am trying to get all unique users in the database, and also pass them into the where query i.e. username = each unique user. Preferably, it could toggle the top part where it says "Report", the current string constant as well.

Comment: Nope. That only managed to confuse me even more. Try going to sqlfiddle.com and creating ddl and sample data. Then you can explain what you want as output and we can help.

Comment: Maybe you just need to change the first column in your select to "SELECT 'Report - ' + UserName as ReportName,"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It hope that I understood what you want:

```
SELECT ('Report - '+ UserName) as ReportName, 
       COUNT(*) Match, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [MyTable]) Total,
       CAST(COUNT(*) AS FLOAT) /
         CAST((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [MyTable]) AS FLOAT)*100 Percentage
FROM [MyTable]   
WHERE OtherCondition = x
GROUP BY UserName;
```

This query delivers the output of the two last queries of your post.